# Deploy ServiceAccount, ClusterRole & ClusterRoleBinding failure

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding, k8s-cluster-role

My NodeJS microservice is deployed to k8s cluster.

I would like this microservice to access the k8s API server.  For that, I guess I need to create a `ServiceAccount` for it. So I did this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-app-service-account
  namespace: myapp-ns
```

Then, I also created a `ClusterRole` to define the permissions:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: myapp-cluster-role
  namespace: myapp-ns
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Finally, I created a `ClusterRoleBinding`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-app-role-binding
  namespace: myapp-ns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: myapp-cluster-role
subjects:
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-app-service-account
```

When I deploy them (I use Ansible to do the deployment), I get the following error:

```
"error": 400, "msg": "Failed to create object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"ClusterRoleBinding in version \\\\\"v1\\\\\" cannot be handled as a ClusterRoleBinding: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ClusterRoleBinding.subjects of type []v1.Subject\",\"reason\":\"BadRequest\",\"code\":400}\\n'",
```

Why this error? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd reckon the issue is with the resources, not with Ansible.

Take a look:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: myapp-cluster-role
  namespace: myapp-ns # <-- NOT A NAMESPACED RESOURCE
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-app-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: myapp-cluster-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount # <-- Added (-)
  name: my-app-service-account
  namespace: myapp-ns # <-- MOVED FROM METADATA
```

To summarize:

- `Clusterrole` is a not a namespaced resource, hence you should not specify it
- You've missed a `-` in the `.subjects`
- You should move `.namespace` from `.metadata` to `.suspects...`

More explanation on namespaced/non namespaced resources:

- `kubectl api-resources`

```bash
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION 
roles                                          rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         Role
clusterrolebindings                            rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRoleBinding
clusterroles                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRole
rolebindings                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         RoleBinding
```

I encourage you to check on the following docs:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access Authn Authz: RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Overview: Working with objects: Namespaces: Not all objects are in a namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#not-all-objects-are-in-a-namespace)*